# How to multiply objects inside an array and for each object, taking one or multiple keys and decrease their values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, javascript-objects

I have this array:

```
const disabledDays = [
       {
         year: selectedDay.year,
         month: selectedDay.month,
         day: selectedDay.day -1
       }
     ];
```

and I will pass it as prop inside of a component:

```
 <DatePicker
          value={selectedDayTwo}
          onChange={setSelectedDayTwo}
          locale={myCustomLocale} // custom locale object
          shouldHighlightWeekends
          formatInputText={formatInputValueTwo} // format value
          calendarTodayClassName="custom-today-day" // also this
          calendarClassName="custom-calendar" // and this
          colorPrimary="rgba(4, 173, 147, 255)" // added this
          disabledDays={disabledDays} // here we pass them      <-    LOOOOK HERE
          onDisabledDayError={handleDisabledSelect} // handle error
        />
```

FIRST PROBLEM: The problem is that **disabledDays** currently, with its first object, is disabling the day before of a selected day with its **day: selectedDay.day -1** and in order to disable all the day before that selected Day I would have to create another object inside **disabledDays** and do **day: selectedDay.day -2** do **day: selectedDay.day -3** .... etc etc one day at the time.

SECOND PROBLEM: So the other problem is that I cannot just do: selectedDay.day -1000000 or infinitely. Also if I do follow the approach of creating an object for each day, everything is bounded by the selected day. So for instance, if the selected day is on the 1st of January doing **day: selectedDay.day -1** won't work because I'd have to rememeber also to subtract also the month and the year accordingly.

THIRD PROBLEM: if i do: (following the 1st of January example) month: selectedDay.month -1, and
day: selectedDay.day -1 it will take the month of December but the again the day wont work, because would be 1 of december - 1 which does not work because does not see November.

Not sure if makes sense, but seems like the only kind of strategy is applying/adding the days manually in the object. I am thinking if there is a dynamic way to do that by multiplying the objects inside the array and for each object, taking one or multiple keys, and decrease their values correspondingly with the selected day. Any clue would be really appreciated. I am using this [library](https://kiarash-z.github.io/react-modern-calendar-datepicker/docs/disabled-days)

Comment: Can you provide the link or name of the lib which you're using for the DatePicker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me rephrase your problem and correct me if I am wrong.

> Disable all the days **before** the selected day using the
> REACT-MODERN-CALENDAR-DATEPICKER component.

As per docs this can be achieved by setting the `minimumDate` for the `DatePicker` component.

A simple implementation is as follows

```
import "react-modern-calendar-datepicker/lib/DatePicker.css";
import DatePicker from "react-modern-calendar-datepicker";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [selectedDay, setSelectedDay] = useState(null);
  const [minDay, setMinDay] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (selectedDay) {
      setMinDay(selectedDay);
    }
  }, [selectedDay]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <DatePicker
        value={selectedDay}
        onChange={setSelectedDay}
        inputPlaceholder="Select a day"
        shouldHighlightWeekends
        minimumDate={minDay}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

If you select 22 September 2021 then all days before 22 September 2021 are disabled.

Reference: [Minimum and Maximum Date](https://kiarash-z.github.io/react-modern-calendar-datepicker/docs/minimum-maximum-date)